# How to set DataTrigger value to const field?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatrigger

I have class with const fields like this

```
Areas
{
  public const int Area1Id = 1;
  public const int Area2Id = 2;
  public const int Area3Id = 3;
}
```

And a template which is binded to Area class.
Area class has int TypeId property, and I want to show different things depending TypeId property

Code like this works perfectly

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="TypeId" Value="1" > 
   ...
 </DataTrigger>
 <DataTrigger Binding="TypeId" Value="2" > 
   ...
 </DataTrigger>
 <DataTrigger Binding="TypeId" Value="3" > 
   ...
 </DataTrigger>
```

Now my question is how to set my const values instead of DataTrigger value

```
<DataTrigger Binding="TypeId" Value="can i bind to Areas.Area1Value?" > 
       ...
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) to reference static fields, static properties, constants, or enumeration values:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TypeId}" Value="{x:Static local:Areas.Area1Id}">
```